# Event system subscribe argument for XPM update preview events

Tags: experience-manager

1. Author updates content using XPM
2. Need to catch the event(Update Preview) in event system.
3. I looked at the TOM.NET API document and didn't come across any event matching to Update Preview (XPM).

need assistance on this.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to capture that event and what you want to achieve in general?

Comment: need to start bundle workflow up on capturing this event with the items updated as part of XPM edit.

Comment: why not on Item Updated (Item Saved) event?

Comment: yes i can use Item save for this. few doubts on the same
1. can't we differentiate XPM & CME events ?
2. Update preview might have multiple items updated and I need to put all of them in one bundle and start workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific event triggered from an XPM edit, since the system just sees an item save. XPM is just another view on the UI so there are no different events triggered.

The update preview by itself is not an item event, so there is also no capture for that.

As suggested in the comments your only option is to trigger on the Item Save event. Furthermore the update preview is not responsible for multiple items being updated, the item save event of each of those items is, the update preview is just reloading your page so it is rendered with the latest data. I might be missing more details from you regarding your bundle workflow requirement, but you will have the same possibilities on an item edit from the CME, so I have a feeling you might be over complicating things by singling out XPM this way.